# Is there a way to export object view status inside of an asset?

Tags: outliner, asset-browser

I'm facing a problem with the asset browser :
I'm building up a collaborative asset library through One Drive for team working purposes, containing some rigged characters. Those characters can have multiple different hairstyles, and I am marking as an asset the collection containing the rigged character and its different hairstyles.

I'm trying to make sure that I only have one hair object that stays visible when importing the asset in a new file, but I can't manage to do that or find a workaround that would suit my needs. I could of course just hide manually all the hair objects I don't need every time I import a character collection asset, but the number of different hair objects makes this process tedious.

Any idea or approach that would help me to achieve that would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers :)

Comment: There isn't as far as I know. The only way to do it is to create multiple collections each with its own subset of visible objects. You can link all other objects with common visibility status to multiple collections to save duplication. I made an addon to ease creation of instaceable collections and duplicating hierarchies https://blenderartists.org/t/collection-utilities-addon/1229359

Comment: One other theoretical way is to control visibility through geometry nodes, but I've never tried it myself, not sure how well it plays with rigged characters

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks for the input, I'll look into the addon and check what I can achieve with geometry nodes :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos seems like going with geometry nodes was the way to go, thanks !
For anyone facing a similar issue, I found this guy solving precisely this (and then just create the asset collection as you like) :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ONw053FlV0

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.